# using variable in the the command resource in serverspec

Tags: ruby, hash, rspec, serverspec

I have the following test in a serverspec recipe - the hash is just the whole resource as it is described in Chef (I am hoping to pipe that in at some point)

```rb
# Test Folder Permissons
# hash taken from attributes
share = {
    "name" => "example",
    "sharepath" => "d:/example",
    "fullshareaccess" => "everyone",
    "ntfsfullcontrol" => "u-dom1/s37374",
    "ntfsmodifyaccess" => "",
    "ntfsreadaccess" => "everyone"
  }

# Explicitly test individual permissions (base on NTFSSecurity module)
describe command ('get-ntfsaccess d:/example -account u-dom1\s37374') do
    its(:stdout) { should include "FullControl" }
end
```

The issue I am having is getting a variable into the command resource - I am new to ruby and and wondering if i am missing something.

I would like the command resource call to accept a variable instead of being hardcoded.

e.g.

```rb
describe command ('get-ntfsaccess d:/example -account "#{ntfsfullcontrol}"') do
    its(:stdout) { should include "FullControl" }
end
```

I have managed to use variables in the `:stdout` test but cannot get them working in the command line.

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable from your hash inside the Serverspec test like this (using modern RSpec 3):

```
describe command ("get-ntfsaccess #{share['sharepath']} -account #{share['ntfsfullcontrol']") do
  its(:stdout) { is_expected.to include "FullControl" }
end
```

The `"#{}"` syntax will interpolate your variable inside a string and the `hash[key]` syntax will grab the value from your hash.

You can also iterate over your hash to perform more checks like this:

```
share.each |key, value| do
  describe command("test with #{key} #{value}") do
    # first loop: test with name example
    its(:stdout) { is_expected.to match(/foo/) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Matt that worked a treat - I had some syntax issues you have cleared up nicely - onto pipping the hash in from chef now.